# Arrange blocks in two columns only css

Tags: css

We need to make sure that there are two columns from these blocks.

```
block block
block block
block block
```

Only html css

```html
<div class="image-row-container container-full section-top">
  <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Zanda_1-1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Sibilla_4-1.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="image-two">
    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Brinuma_meita-15-1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Alina_1-1-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Anda_2-1-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Post your CSS please

Comment: How can I have it if I don't know how to arrange these blocks in two columns? Therefore, I ask

Comment: You haz blocks? Some wiseman once told me that a blank snippet is no good, just saying.

Comment: What do you mean? You currently have 2 columns! & by the way these images links are not working

Comment: At the moment, all pictures go down one column. I need to split in two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version uses simple CSS `columns` and some responsive `<body>` padding. The images stretch to (remaining) available space.

Personally I prefer a 'Flexbox' solution, but this version does not change your HTML and you essentially only need these rules: `.image-row-container { column-count: 2 }` and `img { display: block; width: 100% }` to get things working.

The **snippet** with some comment:

```css
/* all you really need */
.image-row-container { column-count: 2 }
img                  { display: block; width: 100% }


/* EXTRA: eye-candy */
.image-row-container {
    column-gap: 0.5rem;
}
.image-row-container>* {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.image-row-container>img,
.image-row-container>div {
    break-inside: avoid; /* don't split content over columns */
}
img {
    margin-bottom: .5rem
}

body[padded="1"],
body[padded="0"] [band*="padded"] {
/*
    math reference: https://www.mathsisfun.com/equation_of_line.html
*/
/*
    responsive page padding
    and responsive band padding (same as responsive page padding, but at band level)

    Top/Bottom padding: p1(320,16) p2(1920, 72) => 0.035x + 4.8  => vary from 16 to  72px
    Left/Right padding: p3(320, 8) p4(1920,320) => 0.195x - 54.4 => vary from  8 to 320px

    'Band padding' is only active when 'page padding' is off (0)
*/
    padding: calc(3.5vh + 4.8px) calc(19.5vw - 54.4px);
}

/* for debugging */
[outlines="1"] * { outline: 1px dashed }
```

```html
<body padded="1" outlines="0">
<div class="image-row-container container-full section-top">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180?text=Zanda_1-1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180?text=Sibilla_4-1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="image-two">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180?text=Brinuma_meita-15-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180?text=Alina_1-1-1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x180?text=Anda_2-1-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make 2 columns.

please note the images are not loading, so i created a fixed width & height & added a border to be able to see what is happening.

```css
img {
  min-height:100px;
  min-width:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin:10px;
}

.image-row-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
}

.column-one, .column-two {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-row-container container-full section-top">
  <div class="column-one">                 
     <div>Column One</div>
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Zanda_1-1.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Sibilla_4-1.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Brinuma_meita-15-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>                                                                                                   
  <div class="column-two">
  <div>Column Two</div>
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Alina_1-1-1.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Alina_1-1-1.jpg" alt="">
     <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-sparkle/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Anda_2-1-1.jpg" alt="">
  </div>                                                    
</div>
```

**See Snippet below:**

Comment: flex-direction:row; is by default

Comment: Correct! I am writing it out to explain @Nikita Kurilovic how it works